# Boot Windows (7,10,11) installation in GRUB on GPT partittioned USB

Tags: grub, usb-flash-drive, windows-11, gpt, ntldr

The question is why `chainloader +1` works with MBR partittioned USB and can boot with bootmgr but GPT version of my USB stick brings me back to GRUB console after chainloading? Also no luck with `ntldr /bootmgr` command. PC runs in legacy mode (BIOS). `devicemap` and `parttool` doesn't provide its functionality for GPT.

UPD1.
It looks like bootmgr couldn't detect the GPT partition or something like that:
[(BIOS GRUB attempt)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EL6eP.jpg)

If I disconnected all the disks, I get

`File: \Boot\BCD`

`Status: 0xc0000225`

on the bootmgr error screen.

Comment: I am pretty sure you will not start Windows 11 this way.  Can you succeed with just Windows 7 and Windows 10?   Also 3 systems is VASTLY simpler and easier with Virtual Machines.

Comment: @John, in any case, the system either reboots completely (without drivemap) or returns to the GRUB console (most likely loads GRUB itself) or writes that BCD is not found (when the disks are disconnected, either I specify a different root in GRUB or combine with drivemap).

Comment: chainloader in UEFI grub takes a file path (to the efi executable, e.g. bootx64.efi or bootmgfw.efi). Also grub does not support "cross target" booting (if you need to chainload efi executable, you need to install correct efi variant of grub, e.g. `--target x86_64-efi` and make sure your UEFI booted in native mode / that variant, in case you have multiple variant installed).

Comment: @TomYan, thank you for your investigation, but GRUB worked past in MBR partitioned installation and already working with GPT/UEFI on another PC. Now, in legacy mode I have prepared GRUB with `--recheck --target i386-pc` and I couldn't boot windows in GPT/BIOS mode. So GRUB2 sees the windows partition. I can load it with `set root=(hd0,gpt2); chainload +1` or `set root=(hd0,gpt2); ntldr /bootmgr`.

Comment: The BIOS variant of Windows Boot Manager itself (i.e. `bootmgr`) does not work in a GPT installation. If you need to boot a GPT Windows installation, you need to boot a EFI variant of grub / in native UEFI mode.

Comment: Note that if you are having grub on a separate drive, the partition table type of that drive shouldn't matter, since you can have a BIOS/legacy/i386-pc variant of grub installed on a GPT drive. It's just that it can only be used to boot a MBR installation of Windows in BIOS/legacy mode. (You might need to explicitly `insmod part_msdos` in such case though.)

Comment: @TomYan, In fact, I can already count this as an answer, but can I really exceed the limit of 4 partitions and load into (hd0,msdos5) using a logical disk on the MBR partition? I mean the option:
1) GPT partition with bootmgr on legacy?
2) MBR partition with a logical disk on UEFI?
I need a universal formula to solve the problem with system portability later, so I do not know how to do it in MBR and decided to do it in GPT.

Comment: I don't really have an idea on the capability of grub or WBM in supporting logical partition. I am also not sure what portability you are looking for. Are you trying to boot a GPT Windows installation on some old machine with BIOS instead of UEFI?

Comment: No, I'm testing it on my systems with separate but both WBMs (UEFI, BIOS), and I'm wondering how I can boot it using UEFI, which relies on the UEFI `shim` boot mechanism and cannot recognize LDM partitions to boot my binary /efi/boot/bootx64.efi. But if I redo it and install the systems on GPT, I will have the problem described above. GRUB boot is on primary partition always.

Comment: `chainloader` doesn't work with LDM and says: `error: not a valid root device.` when i'm trying to point it on EFI file in UEFI boot mode.

Comment: If you do not need any bootablity for BIOS system, just use GPT for everything and use the correct variant / target of grub and only UEFI variant of WBM(s). No idea why you even think about using LDM ("LDM partition" isn't even a thing. LDM is a Windows-specific *volume* manager. It has nothing to do with exteneded/logical partition btw. Let alone the fact that LDM has been officially deemed deprecated.)

Comment: I need to know how I can boot Windows 10, for example, in UEFI mode. And also Windows 7 in BIOS mode. Sorry, this is not an LDM, but an extended partition (hd0,msdos5...9) on the same device (USB SSD) with one main bootable GRUB partition.

Comment: AFAIK you can't. The only way to do it is to use UEFI WBM for Windows 7 as well, or have Windows 7 on a separate drive. (For the latter option, you'll probably need to find a bootloader that allows you to switch to legacy booting from its own menu, if there's such a bootloader. I faintly remember I heard that rEFInd can do that, but my memory might be wrong. Certainly you can have multiple targets of grub installed and use your UEFI boot menu to switch between them.)

Comment: Is there such a combination of GRUB commands to switch (reboot) to BIOS and to UEFI without using the motherboard firmware setting?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, the boot chain looks like:

`BIOS` => `grub2` => `grub4dos` => `ntboot.vhd` => `Windows`

Detailed:

`BIOS` => `protective MBR of GPT` => `BIOS boot partition` => `grub2 (installed on EFI system partition)` => `grub4dos` => `VBR of ntboot.vhd` => `bootmgr on ntboot.vhd` => `Windows`

---

Steps, stage 1 (prepare `ntboot.vhd` and `grub4dos`):

1. Boot into Windows or WinPE/WinRE.
2. Use `diskpart` to assign a driveletter S: to the ESP (EFI system partition).
3. On the ESP, create a VHD of 64 MB (you may use `diskpart`), partition/format it with MBR and FAT32.
4. Assign a driveletter (like V:) to it.
5. Set the partition V: active.
6. Use `bcdboot /f BIOS C:\Windows /s V:` to create bootmgr/BCD files on the VHD.
7. Write boot code to VHD (however this should not be necessary): `bootsect /nt60 V: /force /mbr`
8. Detach the VHD.
9. Copy `grldr` and `menu.lst` to the ESP (S:).
10. Shrink the partition (like the WinRE partition) for about 8MB to reserve space for BIOS boot partition.

The contents of `menu.lst` may look like:

```
default=0
timeout=5

title [1] -> NTBoot
  map --mem /ntboot.vhd (hd)
  map --hook
  root (hd-1,0)
  chainloader +1

title [2] -> Reboot
reboot

title [3] -> Halt
halt
```

Steps, stage2 (prepare `grub2`):

1. Boot into Ubuntu LiveCD/LiveUSB.
2. Use `gdisk` to create a new partition as the `BIOS boot partition`, utilising the 8MB space reserved above. Change the partition type GUID to BIOS boot partition. (might not necessary) Set BIOS bootable flag in `GPT attributes` to the BIOS boot partition.
3. Get the filesystem UUID of the ESP, use something like `sudo blkid /dev/sda1`.
4. Mount the ESP, the mounted path is `/media/ubuntu/EFI`.
5. `grub-install --target i386-pc --boot-directory=/media/ubuntu/EFI`
6. Create `grub.cfg` under `grub/` directory, fill it with the contents below, **replace FS_UUID with the value got above**:

```
set timeout=5

menuentry "grub4dos" {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root FS_UUID
    ntldr /grldr
}

menuentry "Halt" {
    halt
}

menuentry "Reboot" {
    reboot
}
```